# How to determine column value based on lowest value from other column?

Tags: python, data-frame, pandas

I have the following dataframe with same value in 'nearest_beacon' column but different distance in 'vms_distance' column.

**My Dataframe:**

```
nearest_beacon  vms_distance associated
4548780      0.486456        vms
4548780      0.468065        vms
4548780      0.337609        vms
4548780      0.363601        vms
4548780      0.210566        vms
4548780      0.197327        vms*
4548780      0.285390        vms
4548780      0.216443        vms
4548780      0.441454        vms
4548780      0.337533        vms
```

I want to determine the 'associated' column just one row (*) which has 'vms' value considering it has the lower value in 'vms_distance' column, and the rest is 'no_vms'.

**Expected Result:**

```
nearest_beacon  vms_distance associated
4548780      0.486456        no_vms
4548780      0.468065        no_vms
4548780      0.337609        no_vms
4548780      0.363601        no_vms
4548780      0.210566        no_vms
4548780      0.197327        vms
4548780      0.285390        no_vms
4548780      0.216443        no_vms
4548780      0.441454        no_vms
4548780      0.337533        no_vms
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it is off-topic question. I have moved this question to be asked at another site.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by combining `min()` and `apply()` functions of pandas

```
DF['associated'] = DF['vms_distance'].apply(lambda x: 'vms' if x == DF['vms_distance'].min() else 'no_vms')
```